# Parsing dates without timezone conversion

Tags: java, datetime, groovy, gremlin

I am working with groovy (gremlin to traverse a graph database to be exact). Unfortunately, because I am using gremlin, I cannot import new classes.

I have some date values that I wish to convert to a Unix timestamp. They are stored as UTC in the format: `2012-11-13 14:00:00:000`

I am parsing it using this snippet (in groovy):

```
def newdate = new Date().parse("yyyy-M-d H:m:s:S", '2012-11-13 14:00:00:000')
```

The problem is that it does a timezone conversion, which results in:

```
Tue Nov 13 14:00:00 EST 2012
```

And if I then convert that to a timestamp using `time()`, that gets converted to UTC, then the timestamp generated.

How do I get `new Date()` to not do any timezone conversions when the date is first parsed (and just assume the date as UTC)?

Comment: well, `new Date().parse("yyyy-M-d H:m:s:S" + " Z", '2012-11-13 14:00:00:000' + ' 0000')` comes to mind...

Comment: @vladr: The groovy console just throws an error at me and says it's unparseable :( `java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "2012-11-13 14:00:00:000 0000"`

Comment: @F21 @vladr: That solution works for me if you change it to `def newdate = new Date().parse("yyyy-M-d H:m:s:S Z", '2012-11-13 14:00:00:000' + ' UTC')`. `#parse` is static btw, so unless Gremlin forces you to you shouldn't need to create an instance of `Date` to call it.

Comment: @JustinPiper Gremlins made me do it, I swear! :) (copy-paste that is) | @F21, I'm sorry, the timezone should have been `' +0000'`, not `' 0000'` | @jahroy, I thought the example I gave appended the timezone, don't you? :)

Comment: @vladr - My apologies... I overlooked it (hard to read code in comments sometimes).

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Here are two ways to do it in Java:

```
/*
 *  Add the TimeZone info to the end of the date:
 */

String dateString = "2012-11-13 14:00:00:000";
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-M-d H:m:s:S Z");
Date theDate = sdf.parse(dateString + " UTC");
```

---

```
/*
 *  Use SimpleDateFormat.setTimeZone()
 */

String dateString = "2012-11-13 14:00:00:000";
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-M-d H:m:s:S");
sdf.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
Date theDate = sdf.parse(dateString);
```

Note that *Date.parse()* is deprecated (so I did not recommend it).

Comment: The documentation states that in order to parse the `Z` (uppercase) format then you must specify a RFC 822 time zone (+XXXX or -XXXX).  As per same documentation, `UTC` should theoretically only be parseable with the `z` (lowercase) format. I wouldn't be surprised if in reality `parse` treated the two interchangeably, but just to confirm (not having access to Groovy myself): does your first example above work?

Comment: Yes.  Both examples worked for me (before I posted them).  That being said, I don't have access to Groovy either (I've never used it).  That's why I say: "_Here are two ways to do it in Java_".  To be honest I don't really know what the relationship is between Java and Groovy.  Maybe this answer is irrelevant....

Answer (score 1):

I used Calendar to avoid timezone conversion. Although I did not use new Date(), the result is the same.

```
String dateString = "2012-11-13 14:00:00:000";
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-M-d H:m:s:S");
calendar.setTime(sdf.parse(dateString));
sdf.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
Date date = calendar.getTime();
```

Answer (score -1):

Date class parse(String str) is deprecated from JDK 1.1, try SimpleDateFormat class that supports TimeZone and Locale settings too.

Comment: You're thinking of the Java method. Groovy provides a replacement that lets you specify a format.